# Unhandled Exception Error - Login Failed for User

Tags: sql, vb.net, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

We have a strange error here.  In our ASP.NET 4.6 app, using Entity Framework 6.2, we are getting "Login failed for user" when accessing the SQL Azure database. I'm pretty sure the cause of the error is switching tiers in Azure.  What I don't get is why the error isn't caught.  Every SQL operation we have is inside a try...catch block.  The errors fall out of the block and get caught by Globals.asax just before the app crashes.
We have

```
SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", Function() New SqlServer.SqlAzureExecutionStrategy(10, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7)))
```

which,as I understand it, will retry any SQL execution 10 times for at least 70 seconds from the first error.  According to the Microsoft tech support, this isn't engaged because it hasn't made the connection to SQL Azure yet.  The ConnectRetryCount and interval in the connection string do not apply since it is talking to the server.  The server is just saying, "I know you are there, but I'm not going to let you in!"
According to MS Tech support, the only way around this is to have a try...catch block around all of our SQL commands... which we do! It just falls through and crashes the app!

I can't do a retry in globals.asax because at that point, it is already crashed.
According to MS, there is no way to trap the error in the context and retry from there. So, what's the solution?  There must be some answer other than, "just let the app crash and have them refresh the page!"

When the page is refreshed seconds later, all is fine.  No errors, no problems.

Example of one of the lines of code throwing the error:

```
MapTo = ctx.BrowserMaps.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) code.Contains(x.NameOrUserAgent))
```

It's really very straight forward.  this one just happens to come up a lot because this code block is called frequently.  The actual SQL request is irrelevant because no matter what line is used, the connection, within EF, fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server logins will be disconnected while scaling up/down to a new tier, and transactions are rolled back. However, contained database logins stay connected during the scaling process, and for that reason they are recommended over server logins.

Having a try and catch may not solve the issue because you may be capturing error # zero and a lot of errors in Azure SQL database fall on that error 0 category.

Just a comment, performance after scaling may be poor right after scaling and improves after a few minutes. Query plans may also change.

Comment: This is more or less the answer.  In our case, putting a try.catch in the constructor for the model allowed us to set up some retry logic.  We are looking into database logins now, thank you.